# Remove whitespaces from filenames in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have hundreds of jpg files in different folders like this:

- 304775 105_01.jpg
- 304775 105_03.jpg
- 304775 105_05.jpg
- 304775 105_07.jpg
- 304775 105_02.jpg
- 304775 105_04.jpg
- 304775 105_06.jpg

Basically, I need to remove the SPACES. I already know the command to change the spaces into underscores:

```
$ rename "s/ /_/g" *
```

But I do not need the underscores in this case. I just need to remove the space. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$ rename "s/ //g" *
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
IFS="\n"
for file in *.jpg;
do
    mv "$file" "${file//[[:space:]]}"
done
```

Comment: This works!!! Thank you very much! Can you explain why $ rename "s/ //g" * was not working?

Comment: $ rename "s/ //g" *
works OK for me.  Maybe there is something weird with your environment.  Are you using bash?

Comment: Yes I am using bash. Must be something weird with my environment.

Comment: I am also receiving `command not found: rename` in zsh

Answer (score 42):

The following would work in case it was really a space.

```
$ rename "s/ //g" *
```

Try

```
$ rename "s/\s+//g" *
```

`\s` is a whitespace character, belonging to the set of `[ \t\r\n]`.

Comment: How do you know if it really is a space character? To me it looks like a space. BTW, $ rename "s/\s+//g" * didn't work either.

Comment: @SamTimalsina The underscores substitution worked for you, but the space won't? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: Yep. It didn't work. I downloaded the files off from Dropbox. I have already lost like 2+ hours on this.

Comment: thanks for this, I had no idea you could do this without xargs.

Comment: What is rename here? In my distro (ArchLinux), rename 2.35.2 ( util-linux package). It does not have this options but `rename [options] expression replacement file...`, ie. no 's/ //g' available.

Comment: Does `<expression>` there not take a regex?

Comment: @Artyom `prename` it seems (on Fedora).